# Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance on an object

Tags: javascript

```
 data: [],

 ...
```

I load data from API call into `data` array. Then I try to arrange the data array into a map which can consist of a key, value pairs (value can be itself array) using below.

```
    const dataMap = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i+=1) {
      const key = data[i].product.name;
      const value = data[i];

      if (key in dataMap) {
        dataMap[key].push(value);
      } else {
        dataMap[key] = [value];
      }
    }
```

But when I do the following I get the following error. What I am doing wrong?

```
{[...dataMap].map(([key, value]) => {}
```

> Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

**This is my dataMap**
[image]

DataMap is correctly calculate but when i iterate using the following code

```
Object.entries(dataMap).map((key, value) => {
          console.log(key);
          console.log(value)
 })
```

it prints out the following. Value is some index which i dont understand why ? Value should be an array. My dataMap is a key, value (value is an array)

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images, please explain what does it means "for me it's wrong"

Comment: @DennisVash: I mean why Object.entries value is 0,1,2,3,4.. why not Array(1) value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with react/react-native, its plain javascript:

`dataMap` is already an object, so you only can spread its entries.

```
// An empty object assign.
const dataMap = {};

// Shallow copy
const objShallowCopy = {...dataMap};
```

Also, you can rewrite your for-loops using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const dataSource = [
  { product: { name: 1 }, value: 10 },
  { product: { name: 1 }, value: 100 },
  { product: { name: 2 }, value: 30 },
  { product: { name: 2 }, value: 20 }
];

const dataMap = dataSource.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const prodArr = acc[curr.product.name];
  return { ...acc, [curr.product.name]: prodArr ? [...prodArr, curr] : [curr] };
}, {});

console.log(dataMap);
```

Moreover, `Object.entries` returns an entries array so you need to fix your loggings:

```js
// Bug
Object.entries(dataMap).map((key, value) => {
  console.log(key);
  console.log(value);
});


// Good
Object.entries(dataMap).map((([key, value]), index) => {
  console.log("key", key);
  console.log("value", value);
  console.log("index", index);
});
```

Comment: I updated the issue and still facing some issues.. :(

Comment: I updated the answer, PLEASE don't add questions after someone giving an answer, post another question instead

Answer (score 4):

`dataMap` is object, not an array. You cannot do `[...dataMap]`.

You can convert `dataMap` to arrays of keys with `Object.keys(dataMap)` or to array of values with `Object.values(dataMap)`

So erroneous line should look like

```
Object.keys(dataMap).map(key => /* dataMap[key] will be value */)
```

Comment: Oh yes... correct. I see now that dataMap has duplicated each key. What can be the reason ?

Comment: Please, add samle of input `data` and output result you want to get