# Set a state with the spread operator in React(typescript) returns TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

When trying to use the spread operator to add an object to an array it returns the following error :

```
TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
```

Here is the relevant code in the component:

```
const Component = () => {
        const object = useObject()
        
        const {allObjects, setAllObjects} = useAllObjects();
    
        useEffect(()=> {
            if(object){
                setAllObjects([...allObjects, object])
            }
        }, [object])
    }
```

Code from the context provider

```
    export type AllObjectsContextType = {
    allObjects: any;
    setAllObjects: (allObjects : any) => void;
}

    export const AllObjectsContext = createContext<AllObjectsContextType>({ allObjects: [], setAllObjects: allObjects => console.warn('no allObjects provider')});
    export const useAllObjects = () => useContext(AllObjectsContext);
```

How can I push objects/items to an array using TypeScript and SetState?

Comment: can you put console.log(allObjects); before the spread to check its value ?

Comment: The console.log(allObjects) returns "undefined", if it is inserted before the spread

Comment: i think you got the answer now, make sure you setup Context Provider correctly, `<Provider value={initalValue}></Provider>` and/or set default value for allObjects like this `const {allObjects = [], setAllObjects} = useAllObjects();`

Comment: Possibly duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57245568/invalid-attempt-to-spread-non-iterable-instance-on-an-object

Comment: @somallg Thanks so much, it works. Such a simple solution